# How to create a circular heatmap in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, heatmap

I want to create a circular heatmap in R `shiny`. However, I cannot create a circular heatmap that I created in R in R `shiny`.

```
library(circlize)

# data 
data <- matrix(rnorm(100), ncol = 10)

# Create a circular heatmap 
circos.clear() 
circos.par("track.height" = 0.2) 
chm <- circos.heatmap(data, col = colorRamp2(c(-2, 2), c("blue", "red")))

# Display the circular heatmap 
circos.trackPlotRegion(chm)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be anything special. You can wrap the heat map inside a `renderPlot` and display it using `plotOutput`. Here is a minimal example.

[image]

```
library(circlize)

set.seed(0)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(headerPanel("Circular Heatmap"),
                        fluidRow(column(
                            12,
                            plotOutput("heatmap")
                        ))))

server <- function (input, output, session) {
    data <- reactive({
        matrix(rnorm(100), ncol = 10)
    })
    
    output$heatmap <- renderPlot({
        circos.clear()
        circos.par(track.height = 0.2)
        circos.heatmap(data(), col = colorRamp2(c(-2, 2), c("blue", "red")))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```